# How to disable and Enable ItemTemplate LinkButton based on GridView first and last row?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview with text boxs and two LinkButton Up and Down, I want to make the LinkButton Up and down as Disable, The condition is, Linkbutton Up must be disable for the first row and Linkbutton Down must be disable for the last row.

I am trying to do in onRowDataBound.. But I am unable to do..

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
  // some code?
}
```

Please some one tell me how to do that.. with some test exp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't do it in the OnRowDataBound event, I would disable the controls after the GridView has been bound:

```
// Bind
gv.DataSource = datasource;
gv.DataBind();

// Disable Up/Down LinkButtons
if (gv.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    // With FindControl() if you know the IDs:
    ((LinkButton)gv.Rows[0].Cells[0].FindControl("lb_up").Enabled = false; // Disable up LinkButton 
    ((LinkButton)gv.Rows[gv.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[0].FindControl("lb_down").Enabled = false; // Disable down LinkButton 

    // -- OR --

    // Directly index the controls, assuming Up is at 0, and Down is at 1:
    ((LinkButton)gv.Rows[0].Cells[0].Controls[0]).Enabled = false; // Disable up LinkButton 
    ((LinkButton)gv.Rows[gv.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[0].Controls[1]).Enabled = false; // Disable down LinkButton 
}
```

You could use either the FindControl method or just directly index the controls.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare `RowType` in RowDataBound event. Something like this:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = e.Row;
    if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        .....
    }
}
```

You may add `Down` and `Up` buttons in HeaderTemplate and FooterTemplate respectively.

```
if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
    }

if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
    }
```

Comment: Suppose I have 5text box in Gridview then I have showing up and down btn with all five textbox, and trying to move up and down the text box or you can say moving the text, so what I am trying to do is, when it is the first textbox then up btn should be disable and if it is last textbox then down btn should be disable...

Answer (score 0):

You do same task when You bind your grid like this.Assuming that your link are inside a `asp:TemplateField`.

```
 if (GridView1.PageIndex == 0)
  {
     GridView1.Rows[0].FindControl("lnkUp").Visible = false;

  }
  if (GridView1.PageIndex == (GridView1.PageCount - 1))
  {
      GridView1.Rows[GridView1.Rows.Count - 1].FindControl("lnkDown").Visible = false;
  }
```